# Grouping an object with two attributes

Tags: javascript, lodash

i have an api in rest that return the following object :

**The object**

```
[
    {
      "attributes": {
        "State" : "Las vegas",
        "Period": 1991,
        "People": 6000,
        "Child" : 3000
      }
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "State" : "Las vegas",
        "Period": 2000,
        "People": 5000,
        "Child" : 1000
      }
    }
]
```

I need a group at the like with this :

**My previous return**

```
{
  "People_2000": 
  [ 
    {
      "State" : "Las vegas",
      "People": 5000
    } 
  ], 
  "People_1991": 
  [ 
    {
      "State" : "Las vegas",
      "People": 6000
    } 
  ],
  "Child_1991": 
  [ 
    {
      "State" : "Las vegas",
      "Child": 3000
    } 
  ],
  "Child_2000": 
  [ 
    {
      "State" : "Las vegas",
      "Child": 1000
    } 
  ]
}
```

**Explanation**

For add in table yours values.

I am using the version of lodash :  4.17.4

Also am using vue.js at the version: 2.3.3

my grouping is not as expected,
https://jsfiddle.net/9fh0b3q7/4/

Comment: my grouping is not as expected,
https://jsfiddle.net/9fh0b3q7/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can get all attributes first using [`lodash#map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map), define an array of properties that you want your array of attributes to be grouped with a certain prefix from a certain `Period`. Use [`lodash#reduce`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#reduce) as a way to combine all the grouped properties. [`lodash#group`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) for grouping each of the mapped attributes, and finally [`lodash#assign`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#assign) to contain all the properties and their respective groups into one object.

```
var attributes = _.map(data, 'attributes');

var properties = ['State', 'People', 'Child'];

var result = _.reduce(properties, (acc, property) => _(attributes)
  .groupBy(v => property + '_' + v.Period)
  .assign(acc)
  .value(), 
  {}
);
```

```js
var data = [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "State" : "Las vegas",
        "Period": 1991,
        "People": 6000
      }
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "State" : "Las vegas",
        "Period": 2000,
        "People": 5000
      }
    }
];

var attributes = _.map(data, 'attributes');

var properties = ['State', 'People', 'Child'];

var result = _.reduce(properties, (acc, property) => _(attributes)
  .groupBy(v => property + '_' + v.Period)
  .assign(acc)
  .value(), 
  {}
);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;top:0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: if the grouping was by period and person or child
https://jsfiddle.net/9fh0b3q7/4/

Comment: Are you asking a question? I don't understand, the fiddle you provided is exactly the same as the code I have above.

Comment: i add a property 'Child', the grouping now is for two properties

Comment: Last question, can I get remover as property that is not part of the pool?

Comment: You can use [`lodash#omit`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#omit) for that