# Grouping an object with two attributes for table

Tags: javascript, lodash

i have an api in rest that return the following object :

**The object**

```
[
    {
      "attributes": {
        "CodAP" : 1,
        "Period": 1991,
        "People": 6000,
        "Child" : 3000
      }
    },
    {
      "attributes": {
        "CodAP" : 1,  
        "Period": 2000,
        "People": 5000,
        "Child" : 1000
      }
    }
]
```

**Explanation**

I need to add these values in the following sequence in the table:
[image]

**Versions**

I am using the version of lodash :  4.17.4

Also am using vue.js at the version: 2.3.3

Note: I even asked this question but could not express myself in the best way. Now I think it's clearer what I need. follows my previous post: [Grouping an object with two attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46710540/grouping-an-object-with-two-attributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you mean this?

```
_.groupBy(obj, (v) => v.attributes.CodAP)
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wk7zL0gr/

Comment: it worked perfect as table lines. How would I mount the table header?

Comment: can't header be static?

Comment: It can not be because the return is dynamic, as sometimes they can not have people or children

Comment: ok this mean that when children is not defined, children column will be empty. But header is static.

Comment: It is not static because there is a filter selection between people children and period (there may be more than one)